# Putting items of a list into another list in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a beginner programmer and I'm trying to make a generator. I'm wondering how to put the items of a list into another list. For example, I would want the items of c1 to be in c3. So then c3 would have the items ['chocolate', 'white chocolate', 'plain', 'sugar']. I would just want to do it without having to type it all out, because I'm adding more things.

```
import random

c1 = ['chocolate', 'white chocolate']
c2 = ['chips', 'chunks']
c3 = ['plain', 'sugar']

print "A", (random.choice(c3)), "cookie with", (random.choice(c1)), (random.choice(c2))
```

So, is there anyway I can go about doing this? I know I don't have much so far, but it is growing, and the advice will come useful later.

Comment: What is it you're trying to do?

Comment: Will you clarify what you mean by `put the items of a list into another list`?

Comment: When you say "make a generator", are you referring to the Python language feature called a [generator](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators), or a different use of the word?

Comment: Different word. Ex. A name generator. Where you click a button and you get names from a random list of last names and first names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining lists is easy in Python:

```
newlist = c1 + c2 + c3
```

You can add specific items by `append`ing the list:

```
newlist = []
newlist.append(random.choice(c3))
```